# How can I get the center point of a gridView cell?

Tags: android, gridview

I want to draw a line between two cells in a grid-view depending on user touch? but I need it to be from the center of first cell to the center of the last cell . So how can I get the center point (x,y) of a cell?

This is my code:

```
GridView lettersGrid;
GridAdapter ga;
StringBuilder word = new StringBuilder();
List<Integer> positions = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<String> words;
Methods mthd;
int[] cellsColors;
int randomColor = 0;
Paint paint;
Canvas canvas;
Bitmap bitmap;
float downx = 0, downy = 0, upx = 0, upy = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lettersGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.letters_grid);
    ga          = new GridAdapter(this);
    mthd        = new Methods();
    cellsColors = new int[ga.getCount()];
    paint       = new Paint();
    paint.setStrokeWidth(15);
    Display currentDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    bitmap      = Bitmap.createBitmap(currentDisplay.getWidth(), currentDisplay.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    canvas      = new Canvas(bitmap);

    lettersGrid.setAdapter(ga);
}//end onCreate

    @Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if(v.getId() == R.id.letters_grid){
        int action = event.getActionMasked();


            switch(action){

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    downx = event.getX()+3;
                    downy = event.getY();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    upx = event.getX();
                    upy = event.getY();
                    canvas.drawLine(downx, downy, upx, upy, paint);
                    break;

}


    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: do you want it to be alwayys on the screen? I mean also while scrolling through new cells with differend sizes?

Comment: there will be no Scrolling. Like word search games.

Comment: and... what the touch event has to do with the line? at the moment you are drawing a line from the DOWN position to the UP position.

Comment: everything .. the line get drawn by user touch from the touch-down to the touch-up, I'm trying to develop a word search game, and users has to cross words from the given letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it can be done in many ways none of witch is particularly straigh forward.

the one i might end up implementing is setting a [`OnTouchListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) on every [`GridView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html) child.

that way you always know without tricks wich cell the touch is on at the moment of the [`ACTION_MOVE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_MOVE) event.

on ACTION DOWN

- set up a flag to know that the touch is currently down.
- save the cell on witch the touch is on at the moment with the hash of the view or something like that
- get the center of the view and set it as the start position of the line

`int centerX = (int) ( v.getX() + v.getMesuredWidth()/2d );
 int centerY = (int) ( v.getY() + v.getMesuredHeight()/2d );`

on ACTION_MOVE and ACTION_ENTER

- check if the end position of the line is on this cell coparing the view of the hase
  and if not set the end of the line to be te ceneter of the current view.

I'm pretty sure this could work, those are only guidelines to implement it but i guess you can make it. Not too difficult.

Comment: Thanks that worked with some changes , the formula should be:
int centerX = (int) ( v.getX() + v.getMeasuredWidth()/2d );
int centerY = (int) ( v.getY() + v.getMeasuredHeight()/2d );

Comment: mmm... and what's the difference? i'd edit the answer but i don't see the difference in the forumla

Comment: as I use it to create a custom GridView the getMesuredWidth() gives me the whole gridView Width but with v.getMesuredWidth() I get the cell width, which we need.